# How to get the current location?

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

I want to get the current city name for my application by using latitude and longitude.Is there any other way to get current city than the geocoder??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have to rely on a geocoding service or another 3rd party service for coding the latitude and longitude into a locality (also called "reverse geocoding").

Comment: Well, that or build your own locality service ;)

Comment: True! Although it seems less likely of an option, eh :P

Comment: Nah, it's perfectly viable! Just hire a couple of developers and you could have it done in 6 to 8 weeks! http://www.cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php